# Sending custom app logs to developer

Tags: iphone, ios, logging

I'm planning to release a new app in the future.

I have a custom logging function which logs some application data (not crashes) into a file (location manager state, app foreground-background transitions, main actions...). These logs helped me a lot to debug problems which were app-related, but not causing a crash. Until now these were in the documents directory (shared in iTunes) and the testers sent them to me after they saw some incorrect behaviors, however I don't want to share them anymore because this directory contains the app's database too.

I'd like to obtain these logs even when the app will be on App Store, but I don't know how this should be done. As I wrote, it is a new app and even after the test phase may exist minor bugs. I know that the users can report problems in iTunes or on the Dev site, but without a detailed scenario or log it is really hard to correct a bug. Should I make some kind of in-app bug report functionality (even if this creates a wrong user impression) ? How is this usually handled ?

Edit1 : I'd want these logs only if the user thinks something went wrong and should be analyzed, otherwise I don't really need them. I think some kind of user action is needed to confirm that something isn't working as intended, that's why I asked about making a functionality ( like the "Report a problem" in the Maps App ).

Thanks

Comment: There are tools that do this. Are you looking for a free solution?

Comment: Yes, if there are free ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is gonna crash, don't submit it to AppStore because more likely it will be refused.

I don't know your app but usually logging slow down things. But if you really want logging I would suggest you to first find out if application crashed. For instance in your appDelegate when the app is terminated without problems set some NSUserDefaults value like `closedSuccesfully=YES`. Just after you start app set `closedSuccesfully=NO`, but if it was set to NO before it means your app crashed last time. In that case you could grab your previous logs and try to send them to your server via http post message. On your server there might be very simple php script to get that data. That way it will be automated and your users wouldn't have to do anything and you would get all crashes even these not reported.

Comment: Yes, If i wanted to do manual crash reporting, a most simple approach would be one like this. But, as I tried to clarify in my question, what am I focusing on are more likely app related logs, e.g. user made a photo and it wasn't saved, or a setting wasn't taken into account, which are just bugs.

Comment: I was also talking about your app logs. My point was you can send them automatically not manually.